# Better way for differentiating buttons Swift?

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func followUser(_ sender: Any) {
    if followBtn.titleLabel?.text == "Follow"{
        print("will follow")
    } else if followBtn.titleLabel?.text == "Following"{
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I have a function the runs on load then checks if the user is followed and changes the button's text. Naturally, if the button says "follow" it will have a different function than a button that says "following". Is this the only way I can do that? It feels wrong.

```
func checkFollowing(){

    let url = URL(string: "xxx")

    //request to this file
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    //method to pass data
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //body to be appended to url
    let body = "id=\(user?["id"] as! String)&follower_id=\(imageID)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)   //multi language support

    //launching
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in


        if error == nil{


            //communicate back to UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                do{

                    //get json result
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions .mutableContainers) as?
                    NSDictionary

                    //assign json to a new var parseJSON in guard secured way
                    guard let parseJSON = json else{

                        print("error while parsing")
                        return
                    }


                    if parseJSON["status"] as! String == "1"{
                        self.followBtn.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
                        self.followBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 32, green: 113, blue: 165, alpha: 0.5)
                    } else if parseJSON["status"] as! String == "0"{
                        self.followBtn.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                    }


                } catch{

                    print("Caught an error: \(error)")

                }

            })

            //if unable to proceed with request

        } else{

            print("error: \(error)")


        }

        //launch prepared session
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Do you have a datasource that handles the follow/following?

Comment: Why is it the button's job to tell you whether the user is following already? That's not what buttons are supposed to do.

Comment: You should never use the view as a method of data storage.  What's the function that determines the button's text?  That would be a better starting point.

Comment: No the label changes wether you are following or not. If you press on it when it says follow it will send a request to the backend to follow etc. @Alexander

Comment: I will edit my post to add the function that determines that @JohnMontgomery

Comment: Use the `selected` or `highlighted` property

Comment: @JakeLight And that's my point. It's the not button's label job to provide "following/not-following" data.

Comment: Simplest solution would probably be to just add an `isFollowing` variable to the controller, and set that at the same time you set the text.

Comment: @Alexander Yes I understand, but how do I make the same button do different functions depending on the outcome of the function

Comment: ya that would probably work, thanks @JohnMontgomery

Comment: @JakeLight You have a model that can provide the information on whether the user is following or not, and then you act accordingly. You should be vending this information from a proper model, not via the text on the button. (What happens when you translate the button's text? boom. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracking its status through a variable on the controller would be the better way of doing this.

```
var isFollowing: Bool!

// -------------------------------

if parseJSON["status"] as! String == "1"{
    self.followBtn.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
    self.followBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 32, green: 113, blue: 165, alpha: 0.5)
    self.isFollowing = true
} else if parseJSON["status"] as! String == "0"{
    self.followBtn.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
    self.isFollowing = false
}

// -------------------------------

@IBAction func followUser(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.isFollowing {
        // whatever happens when you're already following
    } else {
        print("will follow")
    }
}
```

(up to you whether you want to make it an optional, implicitly unwrapped optional, or set a default value, but of course if you use a regular optional you'll need to unwrap it for the last part)

Comment: Why make `isFollowing` an optional? Just give it a default value.